# DaskLightGBM memory leaking

Tags: dask, lightgbm

I'm trying to run a relatively large DASKLightGBM task on relatively small machine (32GB RAM, 8 cores), so I cap the memory usage to 20GB... The dataset is about 100M rows with 50 columns. I know it is large, but aren't we trying to do out of core ML?

```
client = Client(memory_limit='20GB', processes=False,
                n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=7)
params = {"max_depth":4,"n_estimators":800,"client":client}
learner = lightgbm.DaskLGBMRegressor(**params) 
learner.fit(dd_feature_009a013a_train[x_columns],dd_price_solely_y_train[y_column_now])
```

However, errors are output and process are dead:

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lightgbm/dask.py:317: UserWarning: Parameter n_jobs will be ignored.
_log_warning(f"Parameter {param_alias} will be ignored.")

Finding random open ports for workers

```
distributed.worker - WARNING - Worker is at 85% memory usage. Pausing worker.  Process memory: 15.93 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 18.63 GiB
distributed.comm.inproc - WARNING - Closing dangling queue in <InProc  local=inproc://172.31.91.159/37355/1 remote=inproc://172.31.91.159/37355/9>
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 26.48 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 18.63 GiB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 26.48 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 18.63 GiB
```

Answer (score 0):

Without [a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's difficult to answer your question precisely.

The "Memory use is high" error could be thrown for a few different reasons. I found [this resource](https://coiled.io/blog/tackling-unmanaged-memory-with-dask/) by a core Dask maintainer helpful in diagnosing the exact issue.

To summarise, consider:

- Breaking your data into smaller chunks.
- Manually triggering garbage collection and/or tweak the gc settings on the workers through a Worker Plugin
- Trimming memory using `malloc_trim` (esp. if working with non-NumPy data or small NumPy chunks)

I'd also advise you to make sure you can see [the Dask Dashboard](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/best-practices.html?highlight=dashboard#use-the-dashboard) while your computations are running to figure out which approach is working.